# Can you make an Ectoplasmator into a staff?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape I see people with what look like an ectoplasmator attached to a staff. How is this possible? It would be nice to make a weapon out of it because it looks good and people say it has a good combat boost. Is this possible or is it just a cosmetic hoax?

Comment: Could you perhaps show us a picture of this staff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the ectoplasmator can not be added onto a staff to create another staff. It is not an orb, nor is it a talisman (here I'm referring to the talisman staves from GOP).

You probably saw an [Armadyl battlestaff](http://runescape.wiki/w/Armadyl_battlestaff), which has the symbol of Armadyl on the top. There's a picture of a player wielding the staff on the page.

The staff does have combat bonuses.

Comment: Whoops, I guess you're right.